# Spring boot cannot find my template view There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I spent almost a day trying to fix this without any luck

i am integrating spring boot mongodb and thymeleaf

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class ItemController {
  @Autowired
  private ItemService itemService;

  @GetMapping("/items")
  public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("items", new ItemEntity());
    List<ItemEntity> items = itemService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("items", items);
    return "item";
  }
}
```

this is my html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>FileUpload</h2>
            <form action="" th:action="@{'/fileupload'}" th:object="${item}" method="post"
                  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fileupload">File Upload(excel or csv)</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" th:field="*{file}"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>All items</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>height</th>
                    <th>width</th>
                    <th>length</th>
                    <th>weight</th>
                    <th>securityLevel</th>
                    <th>file type</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
                    <td th:text="${item.height}">John</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.width}">Doe</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.length}">john@example.com</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.weight}">john@example.com</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.securityLevel}">john@example.com</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.fileType}">john@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.vending'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '2.0.5'
    compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: '1.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image: project structure look like this]

i also have these for mongod inside application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=vending
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

when i run VendingApplication and go to http://localhost:8080/items i get this

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Feb 15 03:26:41 EST 2020
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

it looks like spring is failing to resolve templates view for some reason

UPDATE:

The problem came from the database name which did not map mine

```
application.properties
spring.data.mongodb.database=your_db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In template you are using method as post

```
<form action="" th:action="@{'/fileupload'}" th:object="${item}" method="post"
```

Change it to get and try

```
<form action="" th:action="@{'/fileupload'}" th:object="${item}" method="get"
```

Or in controller change mapping to **@PostMapping**

Comment: already tried that, the post is for fileupload, i was trying to load the front view, then of course i would need to implement the post controller. but still the same result even with get method in the html

Answer (score 0):

For the once who it might concern, the problem for me was coming from the database name on the application.properties `spring.data.mongodb.database`

I had to map it to my document collection